# Use a library from a newly installed glibc in conjunction with --rpath

Tags: gcc, linker, pthreads, libc

I built a new `glibc` in `~/glibc/git/glibc/build`. I know that I can use it to start programs after embedding a path to it and and a corresponding path to loader like this:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main -Wl,--rpath=$HOME/glibc/git/glibc/build -Wl,--dynamic-linker=$HOME/glibc/git/glibc/build/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

`main` will be started by a new libc:

```
$ objdump -p main
  RPATH                /home/user/glibc/git/glibc/build
```

and new loader:

```
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ./main                                                    
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff92df2000)
        libc.so.6 => /home/user/glibc/git/glibc/build/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1097055000)
        /home/user/glibc/git/glibc/build/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f10973f5000)
```

I installed a new `glibc` version 2.22 to `~/glibc-destdir1`. I have 2.17 installed in `/lib64`. I want to use some `pthread` functions that are only available in 2.22 and therefore I try to point `gcc` to use new `libpthread.so` but it doesn't work. This command fails:

```
$ LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/glibc-destdir1/usr/local/lib gcc -std=c99 -Wl,--rpath=$HOME/glibc/git/glibc/build -Wl,--dynamic-linker=$HOME/glibc/git/glibc/build/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  thread.c -o thread -pthread
/tmp/ccSxKt9O.o: In function `thr':
thread.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `pthread_getattr_default_np'
/tmp/ccSxKt9O.o: In function `run_threads':
thread.c:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `pthread_setattr_default_np'
/tmp/ccSxKt9O.o: In function `verify_affinity_result':
thread.c:(.text+0x4eb): undefined reference to `CPU_ISSET'
/tmp/ccSxKt9O.o: In function `do_affinity_test':
thread.c:(.text+0x571): undefined reference to `CPU_ZERO'
thread.c:(.text+0x58a): undefined reference to `CPU_SET'
/tmp/ccSxKt9O.o: In function `do_guardsize_test':
thread.c:(.text+0xa20): undefined reference to `pthread_getattr_default_np'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is this even possible to use a new `pthread` and `libc` here? I know that an old `libc` is still used to build this program and that `libc` as a whole contains a lot of packages and they all have to match but maybe there is a way to do what I want or my understating is incorrect?

Comment: I fixed it, it turned out that `libpthread.so` in new libc installation was pointing to `/usr/local/lib/libpthread.so.0` that didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, it turned out that `libpthread.so` in new libc installation was pointing to `/usr/local/lib/libpthread.so.0` that didn't exist. I just modified it to point to a `libpthread.so.0` in the same directory.